# Excel VBA - I want to insert a date in a 'Get external data' query

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have this Sub with which I receive data from external connection. I already specified a date range :
*((infactln.dtransact>{d '2015-09-01'}) AND (infact.dtransact<{d '2015-09-30'}))*

I want this sub to give the user the possibility to change this date range without going in "Data - Connections - Properties"

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array(Array( _
"ODBC;DSN=Visual FoxPro Tables;UID=;;SourceDB=\\serverName\data.dbc;
SourceType=DBC;Exclusive=No;Background" _
), Array("Fetch=Yes;Collate=Machine;Null=Yes;Deleted=Yes;")),
Destination:= _Range("$A$1")).QueryTable.CommandText = Array(
_"SELECT infact.ctransid, infact.ccode, infactln.dtransact, 
infactln.ccode, infactln.cdesc, infactln.bqte, infactln.bmontant, 
infactln.bcoutant" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM infact infact, 
infactln infactln" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "WHERE infact.kid =" _
, _" infactln.cparentid AND ((infactln.dtransact>{d '2015-09-01'}) AND 
(infact.dtransact<{d '2015-09-30'}))" _)
.RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = False
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Query_from_Visual_FoxPro_Tables"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (and should) use Format function:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx

Than you just give the user opportunity to specify specific dates in some cells, let's say these are "A1" and "B1". You just substitute the date values in your query with

```
" infactln.cparentid AND ((infactln.dtransact>{d '" & Format(Cells(1, "A"), "yyyy-MM-dd") & "'}) AND 
(infact.dtransact<{d '" & Format(Cells(1, "B"), "yyyy-MM-dd") & "'}))"
```

Comment: Hey @Roger, I could not find that part in the original post from you, so I may only assume there is some syntax error with that - most probably it's braces or quote or double-quote signs missing, otherwise you wouldn't get compilation error.

Comment: Thank you GSazheniuk.

I had to remove this part, and put it back after :
AND (infactln.ccode Like 'YY%')

Comment: For a specific date range I use this :
{d '" & Format(Cells(1, "B"), "yyyy-MM-dd") & "'}

What if a want a specific value (for exemple a client code) ?

Comment: If you mean putting Client Id then it is simple you just specify corresponding cell - something like "AND infactln.clientid = " & Cells(1, "A")  - if it's not what you ask for, please give me more details.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean, but when I add :
_AND (infact.ccode = " & Cells(1, "C"))_
I get a invalid caracter error
If I put this instead
_AND (infact.ccode = " & Cells(1, "C") & ")_
The code seams right, but I get a general ODBC Error

Comment: Sorry for the late answer - the best case to debug SQL complex queries is to store them in some cell in Excel, I always keep a 'Temp' sheet there, so I just put Temp.Cells(1, "A") = sqlText and then I can copy&paste it to SQL Management Studio and look for an error. It's much easier then looking for a miising bracket or comma in the Macro Editor :)